# Java Show Threads Working At Same Time

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm playing around with threads in Java for the first time and I'm just trying to convince myself they do what I think they are doing.

I expect the following code to run two loops at the same time, therefore I'm expecting the output to be some a mix of the counters. However, every time I run the code I get a straight count from 1 to 3000 with all the numbers in sequence.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to demonstrate two threads actually working at the same time?

```
public class ThreadDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Loop1 loop1 = new Loop1();
    Loop2 loop2 = new Loop2();

    loop1.run();
    loop2.run();
}


public static class Loop1 implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {
    for(int i= 1; i <= 1000; i++){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}


public static class Loop2 implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {
    for(int i= 2000; i <= 3000; i++){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your question is on most basic threading, and much better to search for and read a tutorial on this first before coming here. You can find the main Java tutorials here: [The Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html). Please save this link and refer to it frequently. I know that I do.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a thread, you need to use the `start()` method. When you call `run()` it is just an standard method call on the same thread that calls it.

You should also try to call `join()` on your threads at the end.

Answer (score 0):

A Runnable is not a Thread.  You need

```
Thread t = new Thread(loop1);
t.start();
```